# Classic programming interview questions

Tags: c++, interview-questions

I'm going to post some of my solutions to common interview questions. I would love it if you could critique me from a C++ purist's standpoint. Also, tell me if there's a better algorithm for each one of these.

**Find the mode (most common element) of an array.**

Note: My solution returns an arbitrary mode if there's a tie; assumes the array is non-empty, too

```
int mode(int* arr, int sz) { 
    std::map<int,int> cntMap;
    int most = arr[0]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
       if (!cntMap.count(arr[i])) {
          cntMap[arr[i]] = 0;
       } else {
          cntMap[arr[i]]++;
       }
       if (cntMap[arr[i]] > most) {
          most = cntMap[arr[i]];
       }
    }
    return most;
}
```

**Sum the largest 2 largest elements of an array.**

Note: Assumes the array contains at least 2 elements

```
int largest2(int* arr, int sz) { 
    int largest(arr[0]), secondLargest[arr[0]];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) { 
       if (arr[i] > largest) {
          secondLargest = largest; 
          largest = arr[i];

       } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest && arr[i] <= largest) { 
          secondLargest = arr[i];
       }
    }
    return (largest + secondLargest);
}
```

**Find whether an array as repeated elements, where it's known that the numbers of the array are between 1 and 100.**

```
bool contains_repeats(int* arr, int sz) { 
    std::vector<bool> booVec(100,false);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) { 
       if (booVec[arr[i]-1]) { 
           return true; 
       } else { 
           booVec[arr[i]-1] = true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: a) It is unlikely that you would be asked for algorithmic alternatives in the interview b) everything in here revolves around arrays/"list"-structures. Unlikely as well during the interview c) You will not be asked in an interview to perform "puristically" or guru-istically. d) Top positions require long-standing previous initiative in the form of community-help, projects, formal endorsements,  and publications. e) Breathe, relax, focus on your strong suits.

Answer (score 1):

- Is the signature of the function imposed ? Your solution would work for any kind of iterable objects and would be probably more idiomatic than passing a pointer and a size. Also, the logic would work for any (comparable) types and not just `int` so it might be worth making it a templated function.
- In your search of the most common element, do you want to return the number of occurences or the element itself ?
- In your sum of the two biggest, I think you can compare to `largest` only once.

You just need to do something like :

```
   if (arr[i] > secondLargest) {
       if (arr[i] > largest) { 
           secondLargest = largest; 
           largest = arr[i];
       } else {
           secondLargest = arr[i]; 
       }
   }
```

Comment: Correct. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Your `largest2` function has at least 3 errors, one of them will prevent the code from compiling: assignments like `secondLargest = largest`, comparision `arr[i] > secondLargest` would not compile because the variable `secondLargest` is declared as an array:

```
secondLargest[arr[0]];
```

The same causes the final addition in

```
return (largest + secondLargest);
```

to become a pointer arithmetics, whose result may surprise you when converted to the function's return type (`int`).

IMHO using parenthesized expression as an initializer for simple arithmetic types is a syntactic overkill compared to the old, good C-style 'equals' form.

When you fix it, either by replacing with `secondLargest(arr[0])` or `secondLargest=arr[0]`, the function will produce incorrect result, for example for input array

```
int testarr[3] = {7, 2, 1};
```

It is quite obvious the largest term in this three-item array is 7 and the second-largest one is 2, isn't it? But your code will store `arr[0]`, which is `7`, both in `largest` and in `secondLargest`, so the value 2 will not get into account (it is not greater than 7, stored in `secondLargest`), and the result will be 14 = 7+7 instead of 9=7+2.

You need to store *two* terms of the input array in your local variables instead  of duplicating the first one. Of course, you need to sort them, so that the initial values of the `largest` and `secondLargest` actually are what variables' names say:

```
    int largest       = max(arr[0], arr[1]),
        secondLargest = min(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

That, however, does not cure the code yet! The routine still returns 14 for my `testarr`. The reason is a wrong starting point of your `for` loop.

Once we store 7 in `largest` and 2 in `secondLargest`, you start a loop with `i = 0` ...and you compare `arr[0]` (which is 7) to `largest` first, then to `secondLargest`. As a result of those comparisions the apparently 'new' value gets stored as a new second-largest, thus making answer 14=7+7.

The corrected code is:

```
int largest2(int* arr, int sz) { 
    int largest       = max(arr[0], arr[1]),
        secondLargest = min(arr[0], arr[1]);

    for (int i = 2; i < sz; i++) { 
       if (arr[i] > largest) {
          secondLargest = largest; 
          largest = arr[i];
       }
       else if (arr[i] > secondLargest) { 
          secondLargest = arr[i];
       }
    }
    return (largest + secondLargest);
}
```

We may also simplify initialization a bit by putting a small value to both local variables - if it only is small enough, it will get overwritten by the actual largest and second-largest term of the array.
Such 'small enough' must be smaller than, or at most equal to the smaller of two first terms. Then we can start iteration from index `0` to consider all terms as candidates:

```
int largest2(int* arr, int sz) { 
    int largest       = min(arr[0], arr[1]),
        secondLargest = largest;

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) { 
       if (arr[i] > largest) {
          secondLargest = largest; 
          largest = arr[i];
       }
       else if (arr[i] > secondLargest) { 
          secondLargest = arr[i];
       }
    }
    return (largest + secondLargest);
}
```